# How process is born in MINIX 3?

Tags: process, operating-system, minix

I am trying to modify scheduling in minix 3.
Till now I am able locate:
-> boot image in kernel/table.c
-> process table in kernel/proc.h
-> priv table in kernel/priv.h
-> initial process table entries (boot image) in kernel/main.c
-> shed(), pick_proc(), enque(), deque() in kernel/proc.c

But i am not able to locate, where/how a new process table entry (for a new process) is created and is assiged its priority, quantum and other process table entries?
Also shed(), pick_proc(), enque(), deque() all are called with a pointer to current process process table. Who calls these function?

Help!

Comment: Please realize there are separate process tables, one in kernel, another in PM and another in (V)FS. Then the details varied depending on the minor version of MINIX 3.

Comment: To learn who call a function, you can either use cross-linked source or simply look through the source using grep. They taught me `enque()` and `deque()` are [not](http://cinnabar.sosdg.org/~qiyong/qxr/minix3/ident?i=enque) [defined](http://git.minix3.org/index.cgi?p=minix.git&a=search&h=R3.1.1&st=grep&s=deque%28).